# Internship: Should I Ask For Relocation Compensation

Tags: communication, internship, hiring, compensation

I've carefully worded my request as such:

*"As you know, I'm based in X and moving to Y for 3 months would entail non-trivial relocations costs. I was just wondering if I could have some information about compensation in that regard?"*

Is this okay? Or should I not ask at all, given that this is just an internship?

Comment: @joeStrazzere thanks for the feedback. And nope, I've still got 2 more years of university to go.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I received a congratulatory email from HR, but not a contract. They basically said "if you're happy, I'll get the paperwork started", to which I asked expressed my interest in the company and asked about relocation compensation.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere right, I sent out the email a few minutes after posting this question ;)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yeah,  it's more of a "cherry on the top" thing, and I'd be fine without it. But it doesn't hurt to ask I guess. Also, I might be hijacking this thread, but: **IF** they send out the legal contract and give me a week's deadline - would it be in bad faith to reject them?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm in last-round stages with a few other places. So if the current company in question sends out a contract on day X, which has submission deadline on day Y, and I receive an offer from another company between X and Y, I would have to choose between the two.

Answer (score 1):

So there's two questions here. Breaking them apart, you have: "Is it okay to ask for relocation compensation for my internship?" and "How do I ask for relocation compensation/assistance?"

To answer the first question ("Is it okay to ask for relocation compensation for my internship?"):

**Yes**, it's absolutely okay to do so. If you're relocating for work, you *should always* ask for compensation. However, the likelihood of you receiving that compensation depends entirely on your specific scenario. Maybe your company does not offer that. Maybe they have corporate housing that they will let you stay in for a reduced cost. Nobody on StackExchange can tell you whether or not the company can offer you anything in terms of compensation/reimbursement; that's information that can only come from your employer.

To answer the second question ("How do I ask for relocation compensation?"):

Not like that. If you're going to ask for compensation, ask for compensation - not for information on compensation. If you're still in the contract negotiation phase, treat this just like you would PTO/Salary/Bonuses/etc. If you're beyond that point, you lose some leverage, but it's still a good idea to ask nonetheless.

Make sure that you state that you would like to be compensated for moving for this opportunity, but express that if that is not possible you are still interested in the position.

Comment: thanks for the breakdown! Yup, it makes more sense to be direct while also making it clear you're still interested.